# Help with date and time in vb

Tags: vb.net, time

My code is below. Every time i debug it, the labels I put in show up as 'Label 1' and 'Label 2' and then switch to the correct date and time as I coded it.

Is there a way that I can make the date and time show up right away instead of showing the 'Label 1' and 'Label 2' first? It's only showing up for a second.

```
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick() Handles Timer1.Tick
        Label1.Text = TimeOfDay

        Label2.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/d/yyy")

    End Sub
```

Comment: Why not make the initial label text empty so the label simply doesn't show until there's a timer event to populate it?

Comment: or repeat this code in the form load event?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your form object, there's a load event.  If you call your `Timer1_Tick()` function from the load event, the label will be updated right away, then on every timer tick.

```
Private Sub MyForm_Load() Handles MyForm.Load
    Timer1_Tick()
End Sub
```